# Why doesn't this array save the scanned numbers?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, while-loop

This is my code. It is supposed to scan numbers until 0 is entered. Then it should print the numbers. But all it prints is zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x[100];
    int n;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        while(x[i] != 0)
        {
            scanf("%d", &x[i]);
            n++;
        }
        if(x[i] == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", x[i]);
    }

}
```

I was expecting to see the exact numbers that I entered.

Comment: `while(x[i] != 0)`: What is `x[i]` to start? It may be 0.

Comment: Like any other local non-static variables.,`x` start out as *uninitialized* and with *indeterminate* values. Don't use uninitialized variables.

Comment: @Jason It can be anything except zero.

Comment: Since it's your first time through an uninitialized array, you'll need to at least populate the data first, then test the input second. You're testing what's effectively junk memory before executing.

Comment: @Coder  I mean.  what is it actually.  Not what are you trying to do.  If that statement is false on the first pass, it will never get to `scanf`.

Comment: Your whole logic is flawed. Please take a step back and rethink what you're doing. Do you really need one loop inside another? Why?

Comment: You should check the input *after* you scan it, not before.

Comment: @tadman How should I do that?

Comment: `int input`, fetch the input however you like, and if it's non-zero, *then* add it to the array. If zero, `break`. Note you're incrementing `n` here for no apparent reason. `i` will be the same thing.

Comment: @Coder Skip the inner `while` loop completely. It's not needed. And add a check (in the `for` loop condition) so that `i` won't become equal or larger than `100` inside the loop.

Comment: You should also cap `i` so you don't run off the end of that array. A condition like `for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)`

Comment: And *always* check what `scanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: You might be interested to learn about do-while loops (different from while loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the early exit is because here: `while(x[i] != 0)` can fail if the uninitialized value (`x[i]`) is 0.  Though it might not be 0.  But this logic is severely flawed in a couple other ways.

- There is really no need to do a while loop since the for loop is already iterating through the array.
- You should really have a terminating condition in the loop since, you could iterate passed 100 and write outside the bounds of the array.
- `n` is uninitialized, so it could actually start counting at any number like 12456 or something =]

Here is what I *think* you want:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x[100];
    int n = 0;  // init this!
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) // added terminating condition here
    {    
       scanf("%d", &x[i]);
       n++;
       if(x[i] == 0)
       {
           break;
       }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", x[i]);
    }
}
```

Also, you should really be checking the return value of `scanf`.  I'll leave that one to you =].

Comment: Also a good idea to check the return value from `scanf`.

Comment: it will not work

Comment: There really isn't any reason `i` couldn't be scoped locally to those loops.

Comment: @Chris Maybe he is using C89 ;)

Comment: @Jason, I love nostalgia as much as anyone, but there are limits.

Comment: @Chris Unless it is an issue, I try to keep the solution as close to the original as possible. *IMO*, a newbie won't learn as much from a re-write.

Answer (score 0):

In your program neither the array `x` nor the variable `n` are initialized

```
int main()
{
    int x[100];
    int n;
    //...
```

They have indeterminate values.

So  evaluation of the condition in the while loop

```
while(x[i] != 0)
{
//...
```

and increasing the variable `n`

```
n++;
```

invoke undefined behavior.

Also the nested loops, the while loop within the for loop, are redundant.

It is enough to use only one loop.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { SIZE = 100 };
    int x[SIZE];

    int n = 0;

    for ( int value; n < SIZE && scanf( "%d", &value ) == 1 && value != 0; )
    {
        x[n++] = value;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", x[i] );
    }
}
```

Pay attention to that you should declare variables in minimum scopes where they are used. And instead of magic numbers like `100` you should use named constants.

Also you should check that calls of `scanf` were successful.